# how can i connect between x.c file to its tester?

Tags: c, include, header-files

i tried to write in the tester file #include "x.h" while both of the files (x.c & testx.c) are in the same source folder , and it didnt work, I had the following error

error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'HNum.h': No such file or directory. 
also there's no main function in x.c (the main is in testx.c) is this legal ?

Comment: error is for fail to include file `HNum.h`.but you show only here `#include "x.h"`. where is `HNum.h`?

Comment: edit your question before it gets closed